# MySQL+PHP: Storing data as JSON vs joins

Tags: php, mysql

I am planing a new database structure for my project and now I am thinking about storing data inside a json-field, instead of creating some joined tables.

I know, that I shouldn't store data into json-fields, which I want to use in WHERE, ORDER BY or similar  commands. But whats about simple 1:n text data?

For example:

```
Table: cities
---------------
id          int
name        string
districts   string (JSON-Decoded PHP-Array)
```

vs

```
Table: cities
---------------
id          int
name        string

Table: districts
---------------
id          int
city_id     int     FK to Table cities
name        string
```

This is just a simple example, but there can be much more complex structures, like:

```
Table: cities
---------------
id          int
name        string
data        string (JSON-Decoded PHP-Array)

// Where data is a json-decoded PHP-Array like this:
$city_1["data"] = array(
    "districts"     => array( 1 => "East District", 2 => "West District"),
    "special_text1" => "This text exists only in 10% of the cities",
    "special_text2" => "This text exists only in 1% of the cities"
);
$city_2["data"] = array(
    "districts"     => array( 1 => "South District", 2 => "West District", 3 => "Northern"),
    "special_text1" => "This text exists only in 10% of the cities",
);
```

So my question is: Is there a problem using json-decoded fields, for example because of performace, etc?

Comment: No. If the intention is - to work with entities as with separate things, then serializing (same as storing as json) - is one of the worst architecture mistakes you can make.

Comment: I don't understand this question really. You're going to save JSON to column `districts`, but what do you want to do with it? Use MySQL to search / filter based on the data in that column?

Answer (score 0):

Saving JSON data in text column is not very good solution, when you want to make a queries on this data.

[PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) enables more functionality on its [JSON type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-json.html) of column.

For your purpose it would be better to use [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/), where the JSON is the native way to store data, it's schemaless, can save complex structures. You can also easily search data in it, which is impossible in JSON saved as text in MySQL database. In Mongo your data can look like this:

```
{
    _id: <ObjectId>,
    name: "City Name",
    data: {
        "districts": [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "East District",
                population: 12221,
                ...
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "West District",
                ...
            }
        ],
        "special_text1" : "This text exists only in 10% of the cities",
        "special_text2" : "This text exists only in 1% of the cities",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: As I said, I only want to store data, where I don't want to query on in such json fields. MongoDB is in my case not a solution, since the other data needs to be in MySQL. I have about 15 tables, where 80% of the fields are "classic" mysql colmns and with the json field, I just want to store data which would be in columns, where in 90% of the cases null values would be stored. I just want to prevent useless columns or creating own tables for them

Comment: If you don't need to query this column and you are sure that you will not need to do this in the future, store it as JSON or serialized array, but I don't recommend it. Creating own table for data with reference to city will be certainly better solution.